# How do I display data through components with Vue.js (using Vueify)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, vue.js

I'm having trouble getting data to display in my Vue components. I'm using Vueify and I'm trying to load an array of listings from the `listings.vue` component and I keep getting errors. Also, I don't understand how to pull in the data via the `computed` method. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the error I'm getting in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions. 
[Vue warn]: $mount() should be called only once.
```

Here is my app.vue

```
// app.vue
<style>
  .red {
    color: #f00;
  }
</style>

<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="listings" v-component="listings" v-repeat="listing"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        replace: true,
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            'listings': require('./components/listings.vue')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my listings.vue component

```
<style>
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="listing">{{title}} <br> {{description}}</div>
</template>

<script>

    module.exports = {

          data: {
            listing: [
              {
                title: 'Listing title number one',
                description: 'Description 1'
              },
              {
                title: 'Listing title number two',
                description: 'Description 2'
              }
            ]
          },

        // computed: {
        //  get: function () {
        //      var request = require('superagent');
        //      request
        //      .get('/post')
        //      .end(function (res) {
        //          // Return this to the data object above
      //                // return res.title + res.description (for each one)
        //      });
        //  }
        // }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 37):

The first warning means when you are defining a component, the `data` option should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      listing: [
          {
            title: 'Listing title number one',
            description: 'Description 1'
          },
          {
            title: 'Listing title number two',
            description: 'Description 2'
          }
        ]
     }
   }
}
```

Also, don't put ajax requests inside computed properties, since the computed getters gets evaluated every time you access that value.

Comment: Why is that @Evan You? The docs also mention [the same thing](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

Comment: Why data has to be wrapped in a function and props don't have to?